# How do I reach this data with Soup? python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the value of data-x and data-y with Soup but haven't succeeded yet.. I do not know how to access it.

```
<span class="coordinatesGrid" data-x="-33" data-y="9" data-did="276" data-villagename="A">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_text = """<span class="coordinatesGrid" data-x="-33" data-y="9" data-did="276" data-villagename="A">"""
BS = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
print(BS.span["data-x"])
print(BS.span["data-y"])
```